# Get row height in flextable after changing column width

Tags: r, flextable

i'm trying to create an automatic adjustment of row heights and page layout for printing flextables to docx with officer. To do this I need to define rules based on row heights in flextable, however when I try to get the row heights from flextable with dim(x)$heights after the column widths have been manipulated, the values are not changed compared to unmanipulated column widths. This is an example code:

```
dff<-data.frame(first=c("This is a very long text that will be wrapped", "etc."),
            second=c(1,2))

t<-flextable(dff)

#autofit table
t<-autofit(t, add_w = 0, add_h = 0, part = c("body", "header"), unit = "in")

#get column widths
dim(t)$widths #3.0978100 0.6778338 

#get row heights
dim(t)$heights #0.2982019 0.3266986 0.2949942

#change width of first column so the text is wrapped
t<-width(t, j=1, width=1.5, unit="in")

#check widths
dim(t)$widths #1.5000000 0.6778338 -->OK

#check heights
dim(t)$heights #0.2982019 0.3266986 0.2949942 --> NOT OK - they are the same as before
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Croatian_Croatia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Croatian_Croatia.1250   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Croatian_Croatia.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=Croatian_Croatia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] flextable_0.6.10

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        digest_0.6.28     R6_2.5.1          evaluate_0.14    
 [5] zip_2.2.0         rlang_0.4.12      gdtools_0.2.3     uuid_1.0-3       
 [9] data.table_1.14.2 xml2_1.3.2        rmarkdown_2.11    tools_4.1.2      
[13] officer_0.4.1     xfun_0.28         fastmap_1.1.0     compiler_4.1.2   
[17] systemfonts_1.0.3 base64enc_0.1-3   htmltools_0.5.2   knitr_1.36
```

Comment: `width()` modify width(s) and does not modify heights. For that, use `height()`

Comment: @DavidGohel Maybe to be more precise. I want to determine should I rotate the page in word to landscape format. If I know that max table width for portrait page is 19 cm, and my table has 5 columns, and the widths of last four is fixed to 14 cm. I want to know if the remaining 5 cm is enough for the text in the first column to be in a single line. I was thinking that solution for this would be to autofit the flextable so everything is in "single line", get the row heights, set the width of first column to 5 cm, and then to compare if the row heights have increased.